# How to fix error identifier "PlayerViewPointLocation" is undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, unreal-engine4

I am following the tutorial https://www.udemy.com/unrealcourse/learn/lecture/4690340?start=150#overview
and it was made before Visual Studio 2015 so I think I am missing an include file but I am not sure which or if I'm missing something else. 
This is the function the error is in:

```
#include "Grabber.h"
#include "Gameframework/Actor.h"
#include "DrawDebugHelpers.h"


#define OUT


// Called every frame
void UGrabber::TickComponent(float DeltaTime, ELevelTick TickType, FActorComponentTickFunction* ThisTickFunction)
{
    Super::TickComponent(DeltaTime, TickType, ThisTickFunction);

    // get player view point this tick
    FVector PlayerViewpointLocation;
    FRotator PlayerViewPointRotation;
    GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint(
        OUT PlayerViewpointLocation,
        OUT PlayerViewPointRotation
    );

    //logout to test
    /*UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Location: %s, Rotation: %s!"), *PlayerViewpointLocation.ToString(), *PlayerViewPointRotation.ToString());*/

    FVector LineTraceEnd = PlayerViewPointLocation /* the error is right here*/ + FVector(0.f, 0.f, 20.f);

    // draw a red trace in the world to visual
    DrawDebugLine(
        GetWorld(),
        PlayerViewpointLocation,
        LineTraceEnd,
        FColor(255, 0, 0),
        false,
        0.f,
        0.f,
        10.f
        );

    // ray cast out to reach distance

    //see what we hit
}
```

Comment: `PlayerViewPointLocation` -- This is not defined anywhere in your code.  The one that is declared is called `PlayerViewpointLocation`.  C++ is case sensitive, if you didn't know already.

Comment: Oh thanks that fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capitalize the p in the declaration

```
// get player view point this tick
FVector PlayerViewpointLocation;
FRotator PlayerViewPointRotation;
GetWorld()->GetFirstPlayerController()->GetPlayerViewPoint(
    OUT PlayerViewpointLocation,
    OUT PlayerViewPointRotation
);
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't tell you where the error is, it is not here.